# Multiple field filter when using aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
{
  "query":{
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "match":{
          "request_1":"rent"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "s": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serial_number"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my query which works fine.

I want inside filter.match I want to add another field so that aggregation happens on result returned when two filter has been satisfied.

I am trying to do something like:

```
{
  "query":{
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "match":{
          "request_1":"rent",
          "request_2":"check"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as suggested I've tried

```
{
  "query":{
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match":{
            "request_1":"rent"
        }
      },
      {
          "match":{
            "request_2":"check"
        }
      }
     ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "s": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serial_number"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which outputs an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "unexpected token [START_ARRAY]",
        "line": 4,
        "col": 17
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "unexpected token [START_ARRAY]",
    "line": 4,
    "col": 17
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

So that I get aggregation from those who only have "rent" in request_1 field and "check" in request_2 field. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "request_1": "rent"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "request_2": "check"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "s": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serial_number"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On very old versions of ES (pre 2.0), you can use this query instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "request_1": "rent"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "request_2": "check"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "s": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serial_number"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran exactly same query but give we "parsing_exception" error

Comment: changed it in my question

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I am using 7.1 and in AWS

Comment: Your query is not exactly like mine. Check mine again and compare it with yours, you'll see that both match queries are not located inside the filter array. You're missing an opening curly brace on the first match query.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't because of that, it was because I had "constant-score" instead of "bool"

Comment: No it was because of that typo (curly brace missing). `constant_score` or `bool` would both work, but glad you figured it out.